# Como ativar o controle de versão no VisualCode?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Estou tendo dificuldades em usar o controle de versão do VisualCode, todas as alterações que faço no sistema não estão indo para o controle de versão, minha dúvida é se eu preciso instalar uma extensão especifica para isto funcionar ?

[image: Segue imagem de exemplo em meu VsCode]

Comment: Você tem o Git na máquina? Está mandando fazer `commits`? E está dando `push`?

Comment: Sim, tudo normal, porém nenhuma alteração que faço está sendo aparecendo ali

Comment: @MikeOtharan de uma olhada [aqui](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol).

Comment: A melhor configuração em vídeo que vi até hoje.
[Configuração VSCode com GIT e Team Services do Visual Studio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QJWP4z3FHhM&t=547s). Este link vai ajudar-te imenso na configuração. Segue todos os passos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O VS Code usa o sistema de pastas do SO, e para que a integração do Git funcione é preciso abrir a pasta que contém o seu codigo, usando como raiz a pasta com o repositório Git, ou seja a pasta que contém, pasta/diretório oculto: .git

É possível fazer isso pelo menu File.

Answer (score 1):

(Se seu provedor for o Git)

Provavelmente foi desativado por algum motivo, se ele já estiver instalado.

passo 1 -> clique nas extensões o vs code.

passo 2 -> busque por @builtin.

passo 3 -> encontre Git em features/recursos se estiver em pt e habilite a função.

Voltará a funcionar normalmente.

Answer (score 0):

Instale o plugin o Power Shell e não se esqueça de 'sincronizar' após o commit, de forma a aparecer na aplicação web. Reinicie o VS Code para o plugin ficar instalado.

Answer (score -1):

Eu consegui resolver este problema, e resolvi por a resposta aqui caso alguém no futuro passe pelo o mesmo que passamos.

passo 1 -> vc vai na engrenagem no canto inferior esquerdo do vs code "Gerenciar" ou "manager" em inglês.

passo 2 -> clica em "turn on settings sync" ou "sincronização de configurações sync" algo assim em português

passo 3 -> vai abrir uma caixa de texto na parte superior, com algumas opções
acredito que logo a primeira vai estar escrito ->
"PLease sign in to synchronize your data across devices.      sign in & turn on"    esse sign in & turn vai aparecer como um botao, clica ali

passo 3 -> vai aparecer pra vc escolher entre uma conta microsoft e uma conta github, clica em github

pronto, agora vc ativou o controle de codigo!!

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).